# Pagination Wordpress in Custom Plugin ( Javascript )

Tags: wordpress

Hi I hope someone can help with this. I'm building a wordpress plugin. I just have basic knowledge of php and i managed to build the whole plugin except pagination. I have tried so many code using javascript but none is working for me. [Here is the image. I want to divide the items with pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPnYG.png)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A good approach will be to think about the pages like tabs. Then the page link will behave like buttons that show/hide based on the page link clicked.

Here's an example using jQuery

```
// Add an event listener for when the page link is clicked
$('.page-link').on('click', function(){
  // Save the page number that was clicked
  var pageNum = $(this).data('page-id')

  // Hide any open 'pages'
  $('.page-content').hide();

  // Find and show the selected page
  $('[data-page=' + pageNum + ']'').show();
});
```

For this to work, you'd need a HTML structure a bit like this

```
<!-- The Page Link -->
 <div>
  <ul>
     <li class="page-link" data-page-id="1">Page 1</li>
     <li class="page-link" data-page-id="2">Page 2</li>
     <li class="page-link" data-page-id="3">Page 3</li>
  </ul>

 <!-- The Page Content -->
    <div class="page-content" data-page="1" style="display: none;">
          Page 1 content
     </div> 
     <div class="page-content" data-page="2"  style="display: none;">
          Page 2 content
      </div>    
     <div class="page-content" data-page="3"  style="display: none;">
         Page 3 content
     </div>
 </div>
```

Here is a super basic [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oukam0bs/3)

Comment: Thank you for your response! This will be one page with multiple answers and I 
just want to separate them with pagination. This code will work?

Comment: @Vlastimir Yeah it should work for you, though theres plenty of room for customization and styling of course, as its pretty barebones. You'll just need to make sure you add the data-page-id and data-page and match them. Guessing you'll do that as part of a PHP while or foreach loop

Comment: foreach loop for sure. maybe you have some styling ideas so you can tell me ?

Comment: Dunno, guess it depends on what youre looking for and the rest of the site. Here's a nice [codepen](https://codepen.io/oknoblich/pen/tfjFl) I found. For inspiration?

Comment: Thank you so much! @dafoxuk